# How to test index/confirm/finish flow pages with rspec and capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I have three pages:

- index
- confirm
- finish

I set a file upload feature in the index page. I check whether the file is a good file when user attach a file and click submit button.

Then show the validate messages in the confirm page.

If there isn't any errors, it will go to finish page and show success message.

Now I am using rspec/capybara to do the feature test. I can test whether user attach a good file or a bad file in the index page. So I can think what messages will been shown in the confirm page.

But I can't `visit` the confirm page or finish page first, because I used a http post method in both of them.

So how to do the feature test on the confirm page and the finish page?

Comment: Could you post the code for your feature tests? Which Capybara driver(s) are you using? Are you using a javascript driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a feature test you wouldn't test the three pages separately, you would test it as one feature using something along these lines (with button names, messages, changed to match your pages)

```
visit index_page_path   # go to your index page
page.attach_file ...   # select a file
page.click_button 'Submit' # submit the file
expect(page).to have_text 'Whatever message shows on the confirm page'
page.click_button 'Yes I want to save that file'  # click the button on the confirm page to do whatever you're doing
expect(page).to have_text 'Whatever message shows on the finish page'
```

You could also test current_path after the have_text methods if the URL the page is shown on is important to you.  You would test the current_path after the have_text because the have_text matcher will wait for the submits to finish and the new page with the text to be loaded.  If you test the current_path before the browser could still be on the previous page finishing up the submit and the test would fail

Answer (score 1):

You should controller test the post method, not feature test it. Something like this

```
describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  it "uses post method to ..." do
    post :index
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect(response.body).to have_content('Hello World')
  end
end
```